# Sending cookie from react app to node js using js-cookie

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, cookies

I am utilizing the 'js-cookie' library in my React application. Upon clicking a button, my objective is to append the user's email to the cookies and simultaneously include this email in the request sent to the backend. The purpose behind this implementation is to facilitate the impersonation of a user. Presently, although the button click successfully generates a new cookie, the said cookie is not being transmitted within the request.

It is important to note that my frontend operates on port 3000, while the backend runs on port 8080, with Node.js serving as the backend technology.

I would appreciate any insights into what might be causing this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Please give us more details. How did you set the cookie (better to add your code to your question)? Any additional cookie flags, like Secure? How did you learn that the cookie isn't being sent?